# Create Distinct ID by Group in Excel without sorting

Tags: excel

I have an Excel column that cannot be sorted and for which I need to create a unique id by group, similar to what is below:

```
+--------+------+
|  Name  | ID   |
+--------+------+
| Jim    |    1 |
| Sarah  |    1 |
| Tim    |    1 |
| Jim    |    2 |
| Rachel |    1 |
| Sarah  |    2 |
| Jim    |    3 |
| Sarah  |    3 |
| Rachel |    2 |
| Tim    |    2 |
+--------+------+
```

Comment: [Okay](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `COUNTIF()` and getting a little creative with your cell references:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, A2) + 1
```

Put that in `B2` (assuming your list with headers starts in `A1`) and then copy down.

`COUNTIF()` here is counting the number of times the name in the adjacent cell has appears in all of the cells above it. As you copy it down, that range will grow to include all cells between `A1` and the next row up.